# Refresh content after clicking navlink reactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like, when clicking on a NavLink, to update the router page instead of just changing it, my pages contain external JS plugins that are not loaded just by changing the page, it is necessary to reload.
My code:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import Teste from './components/pages/Teste';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import { Fragment } from "react";
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  NavLink
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Fragment>
        <div className="app-container app-theme-white body-tabs-shadow fixed-sidebar fixed-header">
          <Header />
          <div className="app-main">
            <Router>
              <Sidebar />
              <div className="app-main__outer">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/home">
                    <Home />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/page/teste">
                    <Teste />
                  </Route>
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
              </div>
            </Router>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The NavLinks is in the SideBar component, so it is not seen there, my "Home" page contains a JS plugin that when coming from the "Test" page, it is not loaded, only when I refresh the entire page. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "update the router page instead of just changing it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force page reloads with the `forceRefresh` prop on the `BrowserRouter`.

[forceRefresh](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool)

> If true the router will use full page refreshes on page navigation.
> You may want to use this to imitate the way a traditional
> server-rendered app would work with full page refreshes between page
> navigation.

```
<Router forceRefresh>
  <Sidebar />
  <div className="app-main__outer">
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/page/teste">
        <Teste />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</Router>
```

If/when you ever upgrade to `react-router-dom@6` this is accomplished similarly via the `Link`|`NavLink` component's `reloadDocument` prop.

[RRDv6 Link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link)

> ```
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   to: To;
>   reloadDocument?: boolean; // <--
> }
> ```

Comment: Can I update just the component? Instead of the entire page?

Comment: @HarrisonMartes Maybe, but in order to provide a more suitable/targeted/scoped solution we would need to see this `Home` component implementation, what it renders, and what exactly are you needing to reload the page/webapp for. What is the js plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the BrowserRouter by using [forceRefresh](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool) property of BrowserRouter:

```
          <Router forceRefresh>
              <Sidebar />
              <div className="app-main__outer">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/home">
                    <Home />
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/page/teste">
                    <Teste />
                  </Route>
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
              </div>
            </Router>
```

Comment: Can I update just the component? Instead of the entire page?

Comment: I think you need to update the State of a component for that

Comment: Here is an article you can follow : [Forcing a React component to re-render](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-when-to-force-react-component-re-render/#:~:text=Forcing%20an%20update%20on%20a%20React%20class%20component&text=In%20any%20user%20or%20system,Virtual%20DOM%20and%20DOM%20state.)